# Drupal 7: modify View display by POST variable

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm looking for a way to change a view's display e.g. from raster mode to e.g. `tabular view/unformated list` by a POST variable e.g. `site.tld/downloads&display="tab"`.

Is there any easy way to accomplish that with `Drupal` Views itself? I'm already importing the whole view (from an export) within a custom module, is this the fastest way of views modification in this case?

Comment: Why don't you use 2 displays with different paths? Every display can have it's own path.

Comment: I'm using blocks, but followed your approach by creating a second view display which I'll load depending on the `&display` by _page_ selection rule. I was using _pages_ already